# PsExec.exe- The network path was not found

Tags: windows-server-2008, psexec

While trying to run a batch file present on a remote machine.

```
.\PsExec.exe \\<IP> -u <username> -p <pass> sample_bat.bat
```

I am encountering below error

> Couldn't access : The network path was not found. Make sure that
>   the default admin$ share is enabled on .

Note- I've enabled AutoShareServer also in regedit.

I've searched all forums but not able to find a working solution.

Comment: What happens when you do `net view <IP>`?

Comment: File sharing is probably firewalled on the remote machine.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've had disabled the firewall completely as a probable solution but still it didn't work.

Comment: @montonero "The Server service is not started" while using net view.

Comment: Check that the Server service is running on both the machine you're using and on the remote machine.  If not, you need to figure out why.  Perhaps file sharing is turned off?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Server service is on both the machines and file sharing also.

Comment: I'm not able to ping the remote machine. I wonder the issue is this only

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you can access the admin share on target machine.

Use the -u & -p options to pass-on the administrator login details but if you're on a domain and the target system is not, or the other way around, you'll have to provide the proper user parameters too (domain\username if target is on domain, or \username if you're the one on the domain and target is not or if domain differ).

Comment: Target machine is on domain and I'm already providing domain\username.

Comment: If I use Remote Desktop Connection app then I'm able to access the machine perfectly. But I want to achieve the same by psexec.

Comment: Can you run a file of the target system ? Try something simple like spawining a 'cmd'. If that works, you'll just have to provide proper (complete valid) path for your .bat file.

Comment: I tried running cmd remotely but still receiving the same error.

Comment: Have you tried FQDN instead of IP?